# Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension

Tags: c#, mime, mime-types

I am looking for a simple way to get a mime type where the file extension is incorrect or not given, something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java) only in .Net.

Comment: This sounds similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739/is-there-a-way-to-infer-what-image-format-a-file-is-without-reading-the-entire).

Comment: I wish I could remove all the "fake answers" still using the file extension when the requirement clearly says DO NOT use extension!

Comment: This may be an old question, but the problem still remains. I would downvote every answer here on the basis they only check Windows executables by their content; what about Linux or iOS executables or dangerous files ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In Urlmon.dll, there's a function called `FindMimeFromData`.

From the documentation

> MIME type detection, or "data sniffing," refers to the process of determining an appropriate MIME type from binary data. The final result depends on a combination of server-supplied MIME type headers, file extension, and/or the data itself. Usually, only the first 256 bytes of data are significant.

So, read the first (up to) 256 bytes from the file and pass it to `FindMimeFromData`.

Comment: How reliable is this method?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833113/why-does-the-findmimefromdata-function-from-urlmon-dll-return-mime-type-applicat, that function is able to determine only 26 types, so I don't think that it is reliable. E.g. '*.docx' file is determined as 'application/x-zip-compressed'.

Comment: I suppose that's because docx is ostensibly a zip file.

Comment: Docx *is* a zip file, *but* the mimetype for .docx is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".  While this CAN be determined from a binary-only examination, it's probably not the most efficient way to do it, and in most cases you would have to read in more than the first 256 bytes.

Comment: I think this question is still relevant in the 20's. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499574/2944723). [FileSignatures Project](https://github.com/neilharvey/FileSignatures) seems a little bit more reliable, and gives you control of exactly what types of files you are matching.

Answer (score 185):

I did use urlmon.dll in the end. I thought there would be an easier way but this works. I include the code to help anyone else and allow me to find it again if I need it.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
    [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
        System.UInt32 pBC,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
        System.UInt32 cbSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
        System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
        out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
        System.UInt32 dwReserverd
    );

    public static string getMimeFromFile(string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filename + " not found");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fs.Length >= 256)
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
            else
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }
        try
        {
            System.UInt32 mimetype;
            FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
            System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
            string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
            return mime;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "unknown/unknown";
        }
    }
```

Comment: or, more precisely, which MIME types are supported?

Comment: Probably whatever is mapped in the registry.

Comment: @flq, @mkmurray http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx#Known_MimeTypes

Comment: I don't understand why you have to set the content type. If you give the user a file to download which contains a file extension, if they have the software to handle that type of file it will automatically open in the correct program. Ex. myPdf.pdf

Comment: I ran into a problem with this code when hosting it in IIS on Windows 8. Using the implementation on pinvoke.net (which has subtle differences) solved the issue: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata

Comment: @Rohland, I too had issues with the above code after deployment to IIS 7.5 on Win2008r2. I was getting process file locks on the files I was attempting to detect the MIME of. And I couldn't duplicate on my own Win7 dev box. After switching to almost identical code you link to, my problems were solved and I could go about my merry MIME-sniffing business. Thx.

Comment: I've been testing this code with IIS 7 and it hasn't been working for me.  I have a CSV file that I'm testing.  I've been changing the extension of the CSV (to .png, .jpeg, etc) and the mimetype changes with the extension (image/png, image/jpeg).

I could be wrong, but it was my understanding that Urlmon.dll determined the mimetype using the file's metadata, not just it's extension

Comment: @Rohland I had issues with the code making app pool crash on IIS 8 on Win2012, and because I had some issues to render that pinvoke.net page on chrome I will post my working code on a new answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22475295/922741).

Comment: Keep in mind that URLMON might not be present on users computer (yes, "Windows without IE" is reality in Europe, you can buy a special license).

Comment: not working well for 64 bit apps, look here instead:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358548/urlmon-dll-findmimefromdata-works-perfectly-on-64bit-desktop-console-but-gener

Comment: if I have a file that was originally .docx and I switched it to .pptx will it still know it is .docx?

Comment: Guys, may I use it for my .net core web API 2.1?

Comment: Be carreful, this code is not working for tiny files : the problem is on the hardcoded 256 when calling FindMimeFromData + the signature of the FindMime is invalid. Please refer to the following working code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826808/how-to-identify-the-extension-type-of-the-file-using-c/2826884#2826884

Answer (score 112):

Edit: Just use [Mime Detective](https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective)

I use byte array sequences to determine the correct MIME type of a given file. The advantage of this over just looking at the file extension of the file name is that if a user were to rename a file to bypass certain file type upload restrictions, the file name extension would fail to catch this. On the other hand, getting the file signature via byte array will stop this mischievous behavior from happening.

Here is an example in C#:

```
public class MimeType
{
    private static readonly byte[] BMP = { 66, 77 };
    private static readonly byte[] DOC = { 208, 207, 17, 224, 161, 177, 26, 225 };
    private static readonly byte[] EXE_DLL = { 77, 90 };
    private static readonly byte[] GIF = { 71, 73, 70, 56 };
    private static readonly byte[] ICO = { 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] JPG = { 255, 216, 255 };
    private static readonly byte[] MP3 = { 255, 251, 48 };
    private static readonly byte[] OGG = { 79, 103, 103, 83, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] PDF = { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46 };
    private static readonly byte[] PNG = { 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82 };
    private static readonly byte[] RAR = { 82, 97, 114, 33, 26, 7, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] SWF = { 70, 87, 83 };
    private static readonly byte[] TIFF = { 73, 73, 42, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] TORRENT = { 100, 56, 58, 97, 110, 110, 111, 117, 110, 99, 101 };
    private static readonly byte[] TTF = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] WAV_AVI = { 82, 73, 70, 70 };
    private static readonly byte[] WMV_WMA = { 48, 38, 178, 117, 142, 102, 207, 17, 166, 217, 0, 170, 0, 98, 206, 108 };
    private static readonly byte[] ZIP_DOCX = { 80, 75, 3, 4 };

    public static string GetMimeType(byte[] file, string fileName)
    {

        string mime = "application/octet-stream"; //DEFAULT UNKNOWN MIME TYPE

        //Ensure that the filename isn't empty or null
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            return mime;
        }

        //Get the file extension
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName) == null
                               ? string.Empty
                               : Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpper();

        //Get the MIME Type
        if (file.Take(2).SequenceEqual(BMP))
        {
            mime = "image/bmp";
        }
        else if (file.Take(8).SequenceEqual(DOC))
        {
            mime = "application/msword";
        }
        else if (file.Take(2).SequenceEqual(EXE_DLL))
        {
            mime = "application/x-msdownload"; //both use same mime type
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(GIF))
        {
            mime = "image/gif";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(ICO))
        {
            mime = "image/x-icon";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(JPG))
        {
            mime = "image/jpeg";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(MP3))
        {
            mime = "audio/mpeg";
        }
        else if (file.Take(14).SequenceEqual(OGG))
        {
            if (extension == ".OGX")
            {
                mime = "application/ogg";
            }
            else if (extension == ".OGA")
            {
                mime = "audio/ogg";
            }
            else
            {
                mime = "video/ogg";
            }
        }
        else if (file.Take(7).SequenceEqual(PDF))
        {
            mime = "application/pdf";
        }
        else if (file.Take(16).SequenceEqual(PNG))
        {
            mime = "image/png";
        }
        else if (file.Take(7).SequenceEqual(RAR))
        {
            mime = "application/x-rar-compressed";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(SWF))
        {
            mime = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(TIFF))
        {
            mime = "image/tiff";
        }
        else if (file.Take(11).SequenceEqual(TORRENT))
        {
            mime = "application/x-bittorrent";
        }
        else if (file.Take(5).SequenceEqual(TTF))
        {
            mime = "application/x-font-ttf";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(WAV_AVI))
        {
            mime = extension == ".AVI" ? "video/x-msvideo" : "audio/x-wav";
        }
        else if (file.Take(16).SequenceEqual(WMV_WMA))
        {
            mime = extension == ".WMA" ? "audio/x-ms-wma" : "video/x-ms-wmv";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(ZIP_DOCX))
        {
            mime = extension == ".DOCX" ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/x-zip-compressed";
        }

        return mime;
    }


}
```

Notice I handled DOCX file types differently since DOCX is really just a ZIP file. In this scenario, I simply check the file extension once I verified that it has that sequence. This example is far from complete for some people, but you can easily add your own.

If you want to add more MIME types, you can get the byte array sequences of many different file types [from here](http://www.mircscripts.org/showdoc.php?type=code&id=2933). Also, [here is another good resource](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) concerning file signatures.

What I do a lot of times if all else fails is step through several files of a particular type that I am looking for and look for a pattern in the byte sequence of the files. In the end, this is still basic verification and cannot be used for 100% proof of determining file types.

Comment: Thanks @ROFLwTIME - I've enhanced this a little to handle when we have a byte array but no filename / extension. (Of course for some mime types it will need to default, or needs to be enhanced further to correctly identify). But if anyone would like me to post the code please let me know.

Comment: +1 for using the bytes. Now one can even take the expected number of bytes for a particular mime-type in order to test it (not a default of 256). However, I'd go for a struct here, with the extension, bytes and mime/type as properties and probably keep a dictionary of pre-defined structs. This would save me endless if-else checks

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Yeah, that is definitely a better architecture than a bunch of if else statements, given that you handle all the different odd-ball cases such as docx/zip and OGG extensions. I didn't really need very many mime types (my actual solution uses 5 mime types), so I chose the lazy route.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, for example, a text file starting with "MZ" will be interpreted as a .EXE file. In other words, you should at least consider extension in all cases, plus a longer signature or per-format heuristics to avoid false positives.

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA +1 for the thoughts, although I do wonder what you consider to be the best answer on here since most just check the file extension. (nothing wrong with that) Heck, I could do more than just check the file ext. and the header of every file, there are tons of things you can check in a file depending on the file type, but then that would get really complex, more than the scope of this question. This answer is a good starting point if you need to do more, but if it's too complex then it sounds like you need hit up a security company that makes a living off detecting files.

Comment: The PNG file signature has only 8 elements according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @Nutshell I believe XLS has a 0 byte at the end whereas DOC does not, so check for XLS first, then DOC. As for XLSX/DOCX, they do share the same signature (ZIP), so to distinguish those you will need to go deeper than reading the header. For example, XLSX files have the string "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels" near the header whereas DOCX files have the string "word/_rels/document.xml.rels" near the header. This is just one of many ways to try and distinguish those particular types and it is certainly not going to cover 100% of scenarios. (ex. Zip file with DOCX/XLSX files in it)

Comment: Hey guys. I´m the one how forked the original FileTypeDetective to MimeDetective at github. I´m happy if it is usefull. And i´v talked with the developer trailmax. We have changed the license to MIT!

Comment: the mircscripts.org link redirects to the home page now, but +1 for that other link :)

Answer (score 98):

I've found a hard-coded solution, I hope i will help somebody:

```
public static class MIMEAssistant
{
  private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> MIMETypesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    {"ai", "application/postscript"},
    {"aif", "audio/x-aiff"},
    {"aifc", "audio/x-aiff"},
    {"aiff", "audio/x-aiff"},
    {"asc", "text/plain"},
    {"atom", "application/atom+xml"},
    {"au", "audio/basic"},
    {"avi", "video/x-msvideo"},
    {"bcpio", "application/x-bcpio"},
    {"bin", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"bmp", "image/bmp"},
    {"cdf", "application/x-netcdf"},
    {"cgm", "image/cgm"},
    {"class", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"cpio", "application/x-cpio"},
    {"cpt", "application/mac-compactpro"},
    {"csh", "application/x-csh"},
    {"css", "text/css"},
    {"dcr", "application/x-director"},
    {"dif", "video/x-dv"},
    {"dir", "application/x-director"},
    {"djv", "image/vnd.djvu"},
    {"djvu", "image/vnd.djvu"},
    {"dll", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"dmg", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"dms", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"doc", "application/msword"},
    {"docx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
    {"dotx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"},
    {"docm","application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"dotm","application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"dtd", "application/xml-dtd"},
    {"dv", "video/x-dv"},
    {"dvi", "application/x-dvi"},
    {"dxr", "application/x-director"},
    {"eps", "application/postscript"},
    {"etx", "text/x-setext"},
    {"exe", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"ez", "application/andrew-inset"},
    {"gif", "image/gif"},
    {"gram", "application/srgs"},
    {"grxml", "application/srgs+xml"},
    {"gtar", "application/x-gtar"},
    {"hdf", "application/x-hdf"},
    {"hqx", "application/mac-binhex40"},
    {"htm", "text/html"},
    {"html", "text/html"},
    {"ice", "x-conference/x-cooltalk"},
    {"ico", "image/x-icon"},
    {"ics", "text/calendar"},
    {"ief", "image/ief"},
    {"ifb", "text/calendar"},
    {"iges", "model/iges"},
    {"igs", "model/iges"},
    {"jnlp", "application/x-java-jnlp-file"},
    {"jp2", "image/jp2"},
    {"jpe", "image/jpeg"},
    {"jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
    {"jpg", "image/jpeg"},
    {"js", "application/x-javascript"},
    {"kar", "audio/midi"},
    {"latex", "application/x-latex"},
    {"lha", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"lzh", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"m3u", "audio/x-mpegurl"},
    {"m4a", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
    {"m4b", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
    {"m4p", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
    {"m4u", "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
    {"m4v", "video/x-m4v"},
    {"mac", "image/x-macpaint"},
    {"man", "application/x-troff-man"},
    {"mathml", "application/mathml+xml"},
    {"me", "application/x-troff-me"},
    {"mesh", "model/mesh"},
    {"mid", "audio/midi"},
    {"midi", "audio/midi"},
    {"mif", "application/vnd.mif"},
    {"mov", "video/quicktime"},
    {"movie", "video/x-sgi-movie"},
    {"mp2", "audio/mpeg"},
    {"mp3", "audio/mpeg"},
    {"mp4", "video/mp4"},
    {"mpe", "video/mpeg"},
    {"mpeg", "video/mpeg"},
    {"mpg", "video/mpeg"},
    {"mpga", "audio/mpeg"},
    {"ms", "application/x-troff-ms"},
    {"msh", "model/mesh"},
    {"mxu", "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
    {"nc", "application/x-netcdf"},
    {"oda", "application/oda"},
    {"ogg", "application/ogg"},
    {"pbm", "image/x-portable-bitmap"},
    {"pct", "image/pict"},
    {"pdb", "chemical/x-pdb"},
    {"pdf", "application/pdf"},
    {"pgm", "image/x-portable-graymap"},
    {"pgn", "application/x-chess-pgn"},
    {"pic", "image/pict"},
    {"pict", "image/pict"},
    {"png", "image/png"}, 
    {"pnm", "image/x-portable-anymap"},
    {"pnt", "image/x-macpaint"},
    {"pntg", "image/x-macpaint"},
    {"ppm", "image/x-portable-pixmap"},
    {"ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"},
    {"pptx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"},
    {"potx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template"},
    {"ppsx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow"},
    {"ppam","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"pptm","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"potm","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"ppsm","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"ps", "application/postscript"},
    {"qt", "video/quicktime"},
    {"qti", "image/x-quicktime"},
    {"qtif", "image/x-quicktime"},
    {"ra", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
    {"ram", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
    {"ras", "image/x-cmu-raster"},
    {"rdf", "application/rdf+xml"},
    {"rgb", "image/x-rgb"},
    {"rm", "application/vnd.rn-realmedia"},
    {"roff", "application/x-troff"},
    {"rtf", "text/rtf"},
    {"rtx", "text/richtext"},
    {"sgm", "text/sgml"},
    {"sgml", "text/sgml"},
    {"sh", "application/x-sh"},
    {"shar", "application/x-shar"},
    {"silo", "model/mesh"},
    {"sit", "application/x-stuffit"},
    {"skd", "application/x-koan"},
    {"skm", "application/x-koan"},
    {"skp", "application/x-koan"},
    {"skt", "application/x-koan"},
    {"smi", "application/smil"},
    {"smil", "application/smil"},
    {"snd", "audio/basic"},
    {"so", "application/octet-stream"},
    {"spl", "application/x-futuresplash"},
    {"src", "application/x-wais-source"},
    {"sv4cpio", "application/x-sv4cpio"},
    {"sv4crc", "application/x-sv4crc"},
    {"svg", "image/svg+xml"},
    {"swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash"},
    {"t", "application/x-troff"},
    {"tar", "application/x-tar"},
    {"tcl", "application/x-tcl"},
    {"tex", "application/x-tex"},
    {"texi", "application/x-texinfo"},
    {"texinfo", "application/x-texinfo"},
    {"tif", "image/tiff"},
    {"tiff", "image/tiff"},
    {"tr", "application/x-troff"},
    {"tsv", "text/tab-separated-values"},
    {"txt", "text/plain"},
    {"ustar", "application/x-ustar"},
    {"vcd", "application/x-cdlink"},
    {"vrml", "model/vrml"},
    {"vxml", "application/voicexml+xml"},
    {"wav", "audio/x-wav"},
    {"wbmp", "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"},
    {"wbmxl", "application/vnd.wap.wbxml"},
    {"wml", "text/vnd.wap.wml"},
    {"wmlc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlc"},
    {"wmls", "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript"},
    {"wmlsc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc"},
    {"wrl", "model/vrml"},
    {"xbm", "image/x-xbitmap"},
    {"xht", "application/xhtml+xml"},
    {"xhtml", "application/xhtml+xml"},
    {"xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},                        
    {"xml", "application/xml"},
    {"xpm", "image/x-xpixmap"},
    {"xsl", "application/xml"},
    {"xlsx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
    {"xltx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template"},
    {"xlsm","application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"xltm","application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"xlam","application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"xlsb","application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"},
    {"xslt", "application/xslt+xml"},
    {"xul", "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml"},
    {"xwd", "image/x-xwindowdump"},
    {"xyz", "chemical/x-xyz"},
    {"zip", "application/zip"}
  };

  public static string GetMIMEType(string fileName)
  {
    //get file extension
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLowerInvariant();

    if (extension.Length > 0 && 
        MIMETypesDictionary.ContainsKey(extension.Remove(0, 1)))
    {
      return MIMETypesDictionary[extension.Remove(0, 1)];
    }
    return "unknown/unknown";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is based on the filename however.  It could be useful for someone, just not the OP, who wanted it done by file contents.

Comment: A subset of this list is also convenient for mapping WebImage.ImageFormat back to a mime type. Thanks!

Comment: Add `Path.GetExtension(fileName).Length > 1 &&` to your condition to prevent it from crashing on files that have no extension.

Comment: Depending on your goal, you might want to return "application/octet-stream" instead of "unknown/unknown".

Comment: Since my edit was rejected I will post here: the extension must be in all _lower_ case, or it won't be found in the dictionary.

Comment: @JalalAldeenSaa'd - an even better fix IMHO would be to use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the dictionary constructor. Ordinal comparison is faster than invariant, and you will get rid of `.ToLower()` and its variations.

Comment: `Unknown/unknown` is just an incorrect content-type. If you don't want to use `application/octet-stream` as a default there should be something that doesn't match the format of an content-type (such as null) to avoid it not being caught and then actually used.

Comment: This is not really a solution. Mime type is about content not about filename.

Comment: The question asked for a way to get the mime type _without_ using the extension. This solution uses the extension to determine the mime type.

Comment: "This is based on the filename however. It could be useful for someone, just not the OP,"  This isn't a form to seek answers to questions the OP didn't ask.

Answer (score 24):

You can also look in the registry.

```
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.Win32;

    string GetMimeType(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        string mimeType = "application/unknown";

        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(
            fileInfo.Extension.ToLower()
            );

        if(regKey != null)
        {
            object contentType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type");

            if(contentType != null)
                mimeType = contentType.ToString();
        }

        return mimeType;
    }
```

One way or another you're going to have to tap into a database of MIMEs - whether they're mapped from extensions or magic numbers is somewhat trivial - windows registry is one such place.
For a platform independent solution though one would have to ship this DB with the code (or as a standalone library).

Comment: @Rabbi Even though the question was specific to file contents and not extension, this answer may still be useful to other people (such as myself) who are passing through.  Even if an answer like this is unlikely to get accepted, it's still nice to have the information.

Comment: does this not simply get the mime based on the extension of the filename? what if the file was a .docx and some clown decided to rename it to .doc? you've get the wrong mime-type surely.

Comment: @kolin, you are absolutely correct, but as the saying goes "make it idiot proof and someone will just make a better idiot." :)

Comment: When working with Windows Azure Web role or any other host that runs your app in Limited Trust - Do not forget that you will not be allowed to access registry. Combination of try-catch-for-registry and in-memory dictionary like Anykey`s answer looks like a good solution that has them both.

Comment: question was about _not_ using file extension

Answer (score 14):

`HeyRed.Mime.MimeGuesser.GuessMimeType` from Nuget would be the ultimate solution if you want to host your ASP.NET solution on non-windows environments.

File extension mapping is very insecure. If an attacker would upload invalid extensions, a mapping dictionary would e.g. allow executables to be distributed inside .jpg files.
Therefore, always use a content-sniffing library to know the real content-type.

```
 public  static string MimeTypeFrom(byte[] dataBytes, string fileName)
 {
        var contentType = HeyRed.Mime.MimeGuesser.GuessMimeType(dataBytes);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
        {
            return HeyRed.Mime.MimeTypesMap.GetMimeType(fileName);
        }
        return contentType;
 }
```

Comment: So far, best library I've tried. Found content type for every file I put in my folder. + .net  Core support!

Comment: Simply awesome. I've also tried many libraries (Nuget packages, custom classes...). This one is the closest to `File -bi [filename]` in UNIX systems.

Comment: This is by far the best library for this, it's wrapping libmagic which is essentially `file` on linux.

Answer (score 8):

I use an hybrid solution:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [DllImport (@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
        System.UInt32 pBC, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
        System.UInt32 cbSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
        System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
        out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
        System.UInt32 dwReserverd
    );

    private string GetMimeFromRegistry (string Filename)
    {
        string mime = "application/octetstream";
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Filename).ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        if (rk != null && rk.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            mime = rk.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
        return mime;
    }

    public string GetMimeTypeFromFileAndRegistry (string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
           return GetMimeFromRegistry (filename);
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fs.Length >= 256)
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
            else
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }

        try
        {            
            System.UInt32 mimetype;

            FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);

            System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);

            string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);

            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (mime) || 
                mime =="text/plain" || mime == "application/octet-stream")                    
            {
                return GetMimeFromRegistry (filename);
            }

            return mime;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return GetMimeFromRegistry (filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  It worked partially.  For both a "doc" and "tif" file it returned "application/octet-stream".  Are there any other options avilable.

Comment: It would be neat to see a hybrid solution of the above extension dictionary and urlmon.

Comment: @PranavShah, note that the servers' knowledge of mime-types (the ones returned by the registry lookup) are subjective to what software is installed on the server. A basic windows installation, or a dedicated web server should not be reliable to know mime-types of 3rd party software that is not needfully installed. Still, it should know what a `.doc` file is.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a validator of mime type. Kindly share it with you.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, byte[]> _mimeTypes = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>
    {
        {"image/jpeg", new byte[] {255, 216, 255}},
        {"image/jpg", new byte[] {255, 216, 255}},
        {"image/pjpeg", new byte[] {255, 216, 255}},
        {"image/apng", new byte[] {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82}},
        {"image/png", new byte[] {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82}},
        {"image/bmp", new byte[] {66, 77}},
        {"image/gif", new byte[] {71, 73, 70, 56}},
    };

private bool ValidateMimeType(byte[] file, string contentType)
    {
        var imageType = _mimeTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(contentType));

        return file.Take(imageType.Value.Length).SequenceEqual(imageType.Value);
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to check for SVG files?

Comment: yes, you can get the correct byte array for SVG by yourself. Just convert several different SVG files to byte arrays. Compare those arrays. The first part of arrays will be the same for all SVG files. This part is a header for SVG files. Then you can validate SVG files by those array.

Comment: I tried, but this doesn't work because SVG has XML content, I tried this by downloading multiple SVGs from the same site all files have the same bytes up to 100+index, also I found this Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) which list header signatures of many formats but SVG is not in the list.

I think for now there is no way for doing it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the right answer is a combination of Steve Morgan's and Serguei's answers.  That's how Internet Explorer does it.  The pinvoke call to `FindMimeFromData` works for only 26 hard-coded mime types.  Also, it will give ambigous mime types (such as `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream`) even though there may exist a more specific, more appropriate mime type.  If it fails to give a good mime type, you can go to the registry for a more specific mime type.  The server registry could have more up-to-date mime types.

Refer to:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

This class use previous answers to try in 3 different ways: harcoded based on extension, FindMimeFromData API and using registry.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class MimeTypeParser
    {
        [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
                System.UInt32 pBC,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
                System.UInt32 cbSize,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
                System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
                out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
                System.UInt32 dwReserverd
        );

        public static string GetMimeType(string sFilePath)
        {
            string sMimeType = GetMimeTypeFromList(sFilePath);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sMimeType))
            {
                sMimeType = GetMimeTypeFromFile(sFilePath);

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sMimeType))
                {
                    sMimeType = GetMimeTypeFromRegistry(sFilePath);
                }
            }

            return sMimeType;
        }

        public static string GetMimeTypeFromList(string sFileNameOrPath)
        {
            string sMimeType = null;
            string sExtensionWithoutDot = Path.GetExtension(sFileNameOrPath).Substring(1).ToLower();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sExtensionWithoutDot) && spDicMIMETypes.ContainsKey(sExtensionWithoutDot))
            {
                sMimeType = spDicMIMETypes[sExtensionWithoutDot];
            }

            return sMimeType;
        }

        public static string GetMimeTypeFromRegistry(string sFileNameOrPath)
        {
            string sMimeType = null;
            string sExtension = Path.GetExtension(sFileNameOrPath).ToLower();
            RegistryKey pKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sExtension);

            if (pKey != null && pKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            {
                sMimeType = pKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
            }

            return sMimeType;
        }

        public static string GetMimeTypeFromFile(string sFilePath)
        {
            string sMimeType = null;

            if (File.Exists(sFilePath))
            {
                byte[] abytBuffer = new byte[256];

                using (FileStream pFileStream = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    if (pFileStream.Length >= 256)
                    {
                        pFileStream.Read(abytBuffer, 0, 256);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pFileStream.Read(abytBuffer, 0, (int)pFileStream.Length);
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    UInt32 unMimeType;

                    FindMimeFromData(0, null, abytBuffer, 256, null, 0, out unMimeType, 0);

                    IntPtr pMimeType = new IntPtr(unMimeType);
                    string sMimeTypeFromFile = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pMimeType);

                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pMimeType);

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sMimeTypeFromFile) && sMimeTypeFromFile != "text/plain" && sMimeTypeFromFile != "application/octet-stream")
                    {
                        sMimeType = sMimeTypeFromFile;
                    }
                }
                catch {}
            }

            return sMimeType;
        }

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> spDicMIMETypes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"ai", "application/postscript"},
            {"aif", "audio/x-aiff"},
            {"aifc", "audio/x-aiff"},
            {"aiff", "audio/x-aiff"},
            {"asc", "text/plain"},
            {"atom", "application/atom+xml"},
            {"au", "audio/basic"},
            {"avi", "video/x-msvideo"},
            {"bcpio", "application/x-bcpio"},
            {"bin", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"bmp", "image/bmp"},
            {"cdf", "application/x-netcdf"},
            {"cgm", "image/cgm"},
            {"class", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"cpio", "application/x-cpio"},
            {"cpt", "application/mac-compactpro"},
            {"csh", "application/x-csh"},
            {"css", "text/css"},
            {"dcr", "application/x-director"},
            {"dif", "video/x-dv"},
            {"dir", "application/x-director"},
            {"djv", "image/vnd.djvu"},
            {"djvu", "image/vnd.djvu"},
            {"dll", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"dmg", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"dms", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"doc", "application/msword"},
            {"docx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
            {"dotx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"},
            {"docm","application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"dotm","application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"dtd", "application/xml-dtd"},
            {"dv", "video/x-dv"},
            {"dvi", "application/x-dvi"},
            {"dxr", "application/x-director"},
            {"eps", "application/postscript"},
            {"etx", "text/x-setext"},
            {"exe", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"ez", "application/andrew-inset"},
            {"gif", "image/gif"},
            {"gram", "application/srgs"},
            {"grxml", "application/srgs+xml"},
            {"gtar", "application/x-gtar"},
            {"hdf", "application/x-hdf"},
            {"hqx", "application/mac-binhex40"},
            {"htc", "text/x-component"},
            {"htm", "text/html"},
            {"html", "text/html"},
            {"ice", "x-conference/x-cooltalk"},
            {"ico", "image/x-icon"},
            {"ics", "text/calendar"},
            {"ief", "image/ief"},
            {"ifb", "text/calendar"},
            {"iges", "model/iges"},
            {"igs", "model/iges"},
            {"jnlp", "application/x-java-jnlp-file"},
            {"jp2", "image/jp2"},
            {"jpe", "image/jpeg"},
            {"jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
            {"jpg", "image/jpeg"},
            {"js", "application/x-javascript"},
            {"kar", "audio/midi"},
            {"latex", "application/x-latex"},
            {"lha", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"lzh", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"m3u", "audio/x-mpegurl"},
            {"m4a", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {"m4b", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {"m4p", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {"m4u", "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
            {"m4v", "video/x-m4v"},
            {"mac", "image/x-macpaint"},
            {"man", "application/x-troff-man"},
            {"mathml", "application/mathml+xml"},
            {"me", "application/x-troff-me"},
            {"mesh", "model/mesh"},
            {"mid", "audio/midi"},
            {"midi", "audio/midi"},
            {"mif", "application/vnd.mif"},
            {"mov", "video/quicktime"},
            {"movie", "video/x-sgi-movie"},
            {"mp2", "audio/mpeg"},
            {"mp3", "audio/mpeg"},
            {"mp4", "video/mp4"},
            {"mpe", "video/mpeg"},
            {"mpeg", "video/mpeg"},
            {"mpg", "video/mpeg"},
            {"mpga", "audio/mpeg"},
            {"ms", "application/x-troff-ms"},
            {"msh", "model/mesh"},
            {"mxu", "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
            {"nc", "application/x-netcdf"},
            {"oda", "application/oda"},
            {"ogg", "application/ogg"},
            {"pbm", "image/x-portable-bitmap"},
            {"pct", "image/pict"},
            {"pdb", "chemical/x-pdb"},
            {"pdf", "application/pdf"},
            {"pgm", "image/x-portable-graymap"},
            {"pgn", "application/x-chess-pgn"},
            {"pic", "image/pict"},
            {"pict", "image/pict"},
            {"png", "image/png"}, 
            {"pnm", "image/x-portable-anymap"},
            {"pnt", "image/x-macpaint"},
            {"pntg", "image/x-macpaint"},
            {"ppm", "image/x-portable-pixmap"},
            {"ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"},
            {"pptx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"},
            {"potx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template"},
            {"ppsx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow"},
            {"ppam","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"pptm","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"potm","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"ppsm","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"ps", "application/postscript"},
            {"qt", "video/quicktime"},
            {"qti", "image/x-quicktime"},
            {"qtif", "image/x-quicktime"},
            {"ra", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
            {"ram", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
            {"ras", "image/x-cmu-raster"},
            {"rdf", "application/rdf+xml"},
            {"rgb", "image/x-rgb"},
            {"rm", "application/vnd.rn-realmedia"},
            {"roff", "application/x-troff"},
            {"rtf", "text/rtf"},
            {"rtx", "text/richtext"},
            {"sgm", "text/sgml"},
            {"sgml", "text/sgml"},
            {"sh", "application/x-sh"},
            {"shar", "application/x-shar"},
            {"silo", "model/mesh"},
            {"sit", "application/x-stuffit"},
            {"skd", "application/x-koan"},
            {"skm", "application/x-koan"},
            {"skp", "application/x-koan"},
            {"skt", "application/x-koan"},
            {"smi", "application/smil"},
            {"smil", "application/smil"},
            {"snd", "audio/basic"},
            {"so", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"spl", "application/x-futuresplash"},
            {"src", "application/x-wais-source"},
            {"sv4cpio", "application/x-sv4cpio"},
            {"sv4crc", "application/x-sv4crc"},
            {"svg", "image/svg+xml"},
            {"swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash"},
            {"t", "application/x-troff"},
            {"tar", "application/x-tar"},
            {"tcl", "application/x-tcl"},
            {"tex", "application/x-tex"},
            {"texi", "application/x-texinfo"},
            {"texinfo", "application/x-texinfo"},
            {"tif", "image/tiff"},
            {"tiff", "image/tiff"},
            {"tr", "application/x-troff"},
            {"tsv", "text/tab-separated-values"},
            {"txt", "text/plain"},
            {"ustar", "application/x-ustar"},
            {"vcd", "application/x-cdlink"},
            {"vrml", "model/vrml"},
            {"vxml", "application/voicexml+xml"},
            {"wav", "audio/x-wav"},
            {"wbmp", "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"},
            {"wbmxl", "application/vnd.wap.wbxml"},
            {"wml", "text/vnd.wap.wml"},
            {"wmlc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlc"},
            {"wmls", "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript"},
            {"wmlsc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc"},
            {"wrl", "model/vrml"},
            {"xbm", "image/x-xbitmap"},
            {"xht", "application/xhtml+xml"},
            {"xhtml", "application/xhtml+xml"},
            {"xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},                                                
            {"xml", "application/xml"},
            {"xpm", "image/x-xpixmap"},
            {"xsl", "application/xml"},
            {"xlsx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
            {"xltx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template"},
            {"xlsm","application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xltm","application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xlam","application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xlsb","application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xslt", "application/xslt+xml"},
            {"xul", "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml"},
            {"xwd", "image/x-xwindowdump"},
            {"xyz", "chemical/x-xyz"},
            {"zip", "application/zip"}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget Try-Catch around registry - you will not be allowed to access it in limited mode which is the case with Azure Web role in limited trust or every other host with limit trust.

Answer (score 2):

I found this one useful.
For VB.NET developers:

```
    Public Shared Function GetFromFileName(ByVal fileName As String) As String
        Return GetFromExtension(Path.GetExtension(fileName).Remove(0, 1))
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetFromExtension(ByVal extension As String) As String
        If extension.StartsWith("."c) Then
            extension = extension.Remove(0, 1)
        End If

        If MIMETypesDictionary.ContainsKey(extension) Then
            Return MIMETypesDictionary(extension)
        End If

        Return "unknown/unknown"
    End Function

    Private Shared ReadOnly MIMETypesDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From { _
         {"ai", "application/postscript"}, _
         {"aif", "audio/x-aiff"}, _
         {"aifc", "audio/x-aiff"}, _
         {"aiff", "audio/x-aiff"}, _
         {"asc", "text/plain"}, _
         {"atom", "application/atom+xml"}, _
         {"au", "audio/basic"}, _
         {"avi", "video/x-msvideo"}, _
         {"bcpio", "application/x-bcpio"}, _
         {"bin", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"bmp", "image/bmp"}, _
         {"cdf", "application/x-netcdf"}, _
         {"cgm", "image/cgm"}, _
         {"class", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"cpio", "application/x-cpio"}, _
         {"cpt", "application/mac-compactpro"}, _
         {"csh", "application/x-csh"}, _
         {"css", "text/css"}, _
         {"dcr", "application/x-director"}, _
         {"dif", "video/x-dv"}, _
         {"dir", "application/x-director"}, _
         {"djv", "image/vnd.djvu"}, _
         {"djvu", "image/vnd.djvu"}, _
         {"dll", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"dmg", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"dms", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"doc", "application/msword"}, _
         {"dtd", "application/xml-dtd"}, _
         {"dv", "video/x-dv"}, _
         {"dvi", "application/x-dvi"}, _
         {"dxr", "application/x-director"}, _
         {"eps", "application/postscript"}, _
         {"etx", "text/x-setext"}, _
         {"exe", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"ez", "application/andrew-inset"}, _
         {"gif", "image/gif"}, _
         {"gram", "application/srgs"}, _
         {"grxml", "application/srgs+xml"}, _
         {"gtar", "application/x-gtar"}, _
         {"hdf", "application/x-hdf"}, _
         {"hqx", "application/mac-binhex40"}, _
         {"htm", "text/html"}, _
         {"html", "text/html"}, _
         {"ice", "x-conference/x-cooltalk"}, _
         {"ico", "image/x-icon"}, _
         {"ics", "text/calendar"}, _
         {"ief", "image/ief"}, _
         {"ifb", "text/calendar"}, _
         {"iges", "model/iges"}, _
         {"igs", "model/iges"}, _
         {"jnlp", "application/x-java-jnlp-file"}, _
         {"jp2", "image/jp2"}, _
         {"jpe", "image/jpeg"}, _
         {"jpeg", "image/jpeg"}, _
         {"jpg", "image/jpeg"}, _
         {"js", "application/x-javascript"}, _
         {"kar", "audio/midi"}, _
         {"latex", "application/x-latex"}, _
         {"lha", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"lzh", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"m3u", "audio/x-mpegurl"}, _
         {"m4a", "audio/mp4a-latm"}, _
         {"m4b", "audio/mp4a-latm"}, _
         {"m4p", "audio/mp4a-latm"}, _
         {"m4u", "video/vnd.mpegurl"}, _
         {"m4v", "video/x-m4v"}, _
         {"mac", "image/x-macpaint"}, _
         {"man", "application/x-troff-man"}, _
         {"mathml", "application/mathml+xml"}, _
         {"me", "application/x-troff-me"}, _
         {"mesh", "model/mesh"}, _
         {"mid", "audio/midi"}, _
         {"midi", "audio/midi"}, _
         {"mif", "application/vnd.mif"}, _
         {"mov", "video/quicktime"}, _
         {"movie", "video/x-sgi-movie"}, _
         {"mp2", "audio/mpeg"}, _
         {"mp3", "audio/mpeg"}, _
         {"mp4", "video/mp4"}, _
         {"mpe", "video/mpeg"}, _
         {"mpeg", "video/mpeg"}, _
         {"mpg", "video/mpeg"}, _
         {"mpga", "audio/mpeg"}, _
         {"ms", "application/x-troff-ms"}, _
         {"msh", "model/mesh"}, _
         {"mxu", "video/vnd.mpegurl"}, _
         {"nc", "application/x-netcdf"}, _
         {"oda", "application/oda"}, _
         {"ogg", "application/ogg"}, _
         {"pbm", "image/x-portable-bitmap"}, _
         {"pct", "image/pict"}, _
         {"pdb", "chemical/x-pdb"}, _
         {"pdf", "application/pdf"}, _
         {"pgm", "image/x-portable-graymap"}, _
         {"pgn", "application/x-chess-pgn"}, _
         {"pic", "image/pict"}, _
         {"pict", "image/pict"}, _
         {"png", "image/png"}, _
         {"pnm", "image/x-portable-anymap"}, _
         {"pnt", "image/x-macpaint"}, _
         {"pntg", "image/x-macpaint"}, _
         {"ppm", "image/x-portable-pixmap"}, _
         {"ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"}, _
         {"ps", "application/postscript"}, _
         {"qt", "video/quicktime"}, _
         {"qti", "image/x-quicktime"}, _
         {"qtif", "image/x-quicktime"}, _
         {"ra", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"}, _
         {"ram", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"}, _
         {"ras", "image/x-cmu-raster"}, _
         {"rdf", "application/rdf+xml"}, _
         {"rgb", "image/x-rgb"}, _
         {"rm", "application/vnd.rn-realmedia"}, _
         {"roff", "application/x-troff"}, _
         {"rtf", "text/rtf"}, _
         {"rtx", "text/richtext"}, _
         {"sgm", "text/sgml"}, _
         {"sgml", "text/sgml"}, _
         {"sh", "application/x-sh"}, _
         {"shar", "application/x-shar"}, _
         {"silo", "model/mesh"}, _
         {"sit", "application/x-stuffit"}, _
         {"skd", "application/x-koan"}, _
         {"skm", "application/x-koan"}, _
         {"skp", "application/x-koan"}, _
         {"skt", "application/x-koan"}, _
         {"smi", "application/smil"}, _
         {"smil", "application/smil"}, _
         {"snd", "audio/basic"}, _
         {"so", "application/octet-stream"}, _
         {"spl", "application/x-futuresplash"}, _
         {"src", "application/x-wais-source"}, _
         {"sv4cpio", "application/x-sv4cpio"}, _
         {"sv4crc", "application/x-sv4crc"}, _
         {"svg", "image/svg+xml"}, _
         {"swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash"}, _
         {"t", "application/x-troff"}, _
         {"tar", "application/x-tar"}, _
         {"tcl", "application/x-tcl"}, _
         {"tex", "application/x-tex"}, _
         {"texi", "application/x-texinfo"}, _
         {"texinfo", "application/x-texinfo"}, _
         {"tif", "image/tiff"}, _
         {"tiff", "image/tiff"}, _
         {"tr", "application/x-troff"}, _
         {"tsv", "text/tab-separated-values"}, _
         {"txt", "text/plain"}, _
         {"ustar", "application/x-ustar"}, _
         {"vcd", "application/x-cdlink"}, _
         {"vrml", "model/vrml"}, _
         {"vxml", "application/voicexml+xml"}, _
         {"wav", "audio/x-wav"}, _
         {"wbmp", "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"}, _
         {"wbmxl", "application/vnd.wap.wbxml"}, _
         {"wml", "text/vnd.wap.wml"}, _
         {"wmlc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlc"}, _
         {"wmls", "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript"}, _
         {"wmlsc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc"}, _
         {"wrl", "model/vrml"}, _
         {"xbm", "image/x-xbitmap"}, _
         {"xht", "application/xhtml+xml"}, _
         {"xhtml", "application/xhtml+xml"}, _
         {"xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"}, _
         {"xml", "application/xml"}, _
         {"xpm", "image/x-xpixmap"}, _
         {"xsl", "application/xml"}, _
         {"xslt", "application/xslt+xml"}, _
         {"xul", "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml"}, _
         {"xwd", "image/x-xwindowdump"}, _
         {"xyz", "chemical/x-xyz"}, _
         {"zip", "application/zip"} _
        }
```

Comment: looks like it may be an old list... no .docx, .xlsx, etc.

Comment: Is there an online list somewhere?  The above list looked a little more complete, and found some of the missing ones, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc -- but it seems there should be a web service somewhere that you can just send a filename and some bytes too that can make a best guess and figure the rest out...

Comment: I'd use configuration for this, so I can choose the mime-types I need and modify them accordingly, without changing a single line of code

Answer (score 2):

If someone was up for it they could port the excellent perl module [File::Type](http://search.cpan.org/~pmison/File-Type-0.22/lib/File/Type.pm) to .NET. In the code is a set of file header magic number look ups for each file type or regex matches.

Here's a .NET file type detecting library http://filetypedetective.codeplex.com/ but it only detects a smallish number of files at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a copy of the author's answer (Richard Gourlay), but improved to solve issues on IIS 8 / win2012 (where function would cause app pool to crash), based on Rohland's comment pointing to http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.findmimefromdata

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
public static string GetMimeFromFile(string filename)
{

    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(filename + " not found");

    const int maxContent = 256;

    var buffer = new byte[maxContent];
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        if (fs.Length >= maxContent)
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, maxContent);
        else
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int) fs.Length);
    }

    var mimeTypePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        var result = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, null, buffer, maxContent, null, 0, out mimeTypePtr, 0);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
            throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(result);
        }

        var mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
        return mime;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (mimeTypePtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
        }
        return "unknown/unknown";
    }
}

[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
private static extern int FindMimeFromData(IntPtr pBC,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzUrl,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1, SizeParamIndex = 3)] byte[] pBuffer,
    int cbSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzMimeProposed,
    int dwMimeFlags,
    out IntPtr ppwzMimeOut,
    int dwReserved);
```

Comment: Nice C+P able answer. Chrs

Answer (score 2):

@Steve Morgan and @Richard Gourlay this is a great solution, thank you for that.  One small drawback is that when the number of bytes in a file is 255 or below, the mime type will sometimes yield "application/octet-stream", which is slightly inaccurate for files which would be expected to yield "text/plain".  I have updated your original method to account for this situation as follows:

If the number of bytes in the file is less than or equal to 255 and the deduced mime type is "application/octet-stream", then create a new byte array that consists of the original file bytes repeated n-times until the total number of bytes is >= 256.  Then re-check the mime-type on that new byte array.

Modified method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindMimeFromData(pBC As System.UInt32, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> pwzUrl As System.String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> pBuffer As Byte(), cbSize As System.UInt32, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> pwzMimeProposed As System.String, dwMimeFlags As System.UInt32, _
ByRef ppwzMimeOut As System.UInt32, dwReserverd As System.UInt32) As System.UInt32
End Function
Private Function GetMimeType(ByVal f As FileInfo) As String
    'See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature
    Dim returnValue As String = ""
    Dim fileStream As FileStream = Nothing
    Dim fileStreamLength As Long = 0
    Dim fileStreamIsLessThanBByteSize As Boolean = False

    Const byteSize As Integer = 255
    Const bbyteSize As Integer = byteSize + 1

    Const ambiguousMimeType As String = "application/octet-stream"
    Const unknownMimeType As String = "unknown/unknown"

    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(byteSize) {}
    Dim fnGetMimeTypeValue As New Func(Of Byte(), Integer, String)(
        Function(_buffer As Byte(), _bbyteSize As Integer) As String
            Dim _returnValue As String = ""
            Dim mimeType As UInt32 = 0
            FindMimeFromData(0, Nothing, _buffer, _bbyteSize, Nothing, 0, mimeType, 0)
            Dim mimeTypePtr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(mimeType)
            _returnValue = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr)
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr)
            Return _returnValue
        End Function)

    If (f.Exists()) Then
        Try
            fileStream = New FileStream(f.FullName(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            fileStreamLength = fileStream.Length()

            If (fileStreamLength >= bbyteSize) Then
                fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bbyteSize)
            Else
                fileStreamIsLessThanBByteSize = True
                fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, CInt(fileStreamLength))
            End If

            returnValue = fnGetMimeTypeValue(buffer, bbyteSize)

            If (returnValue.Equals(ambiguousMimeType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso fileStreamIsLessThanBByteSize AndAlso fileStreamLength > 0) Then
                'Duplicate the stream content until the stream length is >= bbyteSize to get a more deterministic mime type analysis.
                Dim currentBuffer As Byte() = buffer.Take(fileStreamLength).ToArray()
                Dim repeatCount As Integer = Math.Floor((bbyteSize / fileStreamLength) + 1)
                Dim bBufferList As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)
                While (repeatCount > 0)
                    bBufferList.AddRange(currentBuffer)
                    repeatCount -= 1
                End While
                Dim bbuffer As Byte() = bBufferList.Take(bbyteSize).ToArray()
                returnValue = fnGetMimeTypeValue(bbuffer, bbyteSize)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            returnValue = unknownMimeType
        Finally
            If (fileStream IsNot Nothing) Then fileStream.Close()
        End Try
    End If
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: This was the issue I had, and your idea was great, to copy the bytes. I had to implement it in c#, but using the length of the file, and the buffer that has the first bytes of the file, i was able to iterate over all missing bytes and copy the bytes in the array to repeat the file (i just copied the byte from the idx that was the file length earlier in the array).

Answer (score 1):

IIS 7 or more

Use this code, but you need to be the admin on the server

```
public bool CheckMimeMapExtension(string fileExtension)
        {
            try
            {

                using (
                ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
                {   
                    // connects to default app.config
                    var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                    var staticContent = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
                    var mimeMap = staticContent.GetCollection();

                    foreach (var mimeType in mimeMap)
                    {

                        if (((String)mimeType["fileExtension"]).Equals(fileExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            return true;

                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("An exception has occurred: \n{0}", ex.Message);
                Console.Read();
            }

            return false;

        }
```

Comment: What about spoofing?

Answer (score 0):

When working with Windows Azure Web role or any other host that runs your app in Limited Trust do not forget that you will not be allowed to access registry or unmanaged code. Hybrid approach - combination of try-catch-for-registry and in-memory dictionary looks like a good solution that has a bit of everything.

I use this code to do it :

```
public class DefaultMimeResolver : IMimeResolver
{
    private readonly IFileRepository _fileRepository;

    public DefaultMimeResolver(IFileRepository fileRepository)
    {
        _fileRepository = fileRepository;
    }

    [DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
        System.UInt32 pBC, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
         System.UInt32 cbSize,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
         System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
         out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
         System.UInt32 dwReserverd);


    public string GetMimeTypeFromFileExtension(string fileExtension)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileExtension");
        }

        string mimeType = GetMimeTypeFromList(fileExtension);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType))
        {
            mimeType = GetMimeTypeFromRegistry(fileExtension);
        }

        return mimeType;
    }

    public string GetMimeTypeFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found : ", filePath);
        }

        string mimeType = GetMimeTypeFromList(Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower());

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType))
        {
            mimeType = GetMimeTypeFromRegistry(Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower());

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType))
            {
                mimeType = GetMimeTypeFromFileInternal(filePath);
            }
        }

        return mimeType;
    }

    private string GetMimeTypeFromList(string fileExtension)
    {
        string mimeType = null;

        if (fileExtension.StartsWith("."))
        {
            fileExtension = fileExtension.TrimStart('.');
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension) && _mimeTypes.ContainsKey(fileExtension))
        {
            mimeType = _mimeTypes[fileExtension];
        }

        return mimeType;
    }

    private string GetMimeTypeFromRegistry(string fileExtension)
    {
        string mimeType = null;
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(fileExtension);

            if (key != null && key.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            {
                mimeType = key.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Empty. When this code is running in limited mode accessing registry is not allowed.
        }

        return mimeType;
    }

    private string GetMimeTypeFromFileInternal(string filePath)
    {
        string mimeType = null;

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[256];

        using (FileStream fileStream = _fileRepository.Get(filePath))
        {
            if (fileStream.Length >= 256)
            {
                fileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 256);
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            UInt32 MimeTypeNum;

            FindMimeFromData(0, null, byteBuffer, 256, null, 0, out MimeTypeNum, 0);

            IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(MimeTypeNum);
            string mimeTypeFromFile = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);

            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeTypeFromFile) && mimeTypeFromFile != "text/plain" && mimeTypeFromFile != "application/octet-stream")
            {
                mimeType = mimeTypeFromFile;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Empty. 
        }

        return mimeType;
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mimeTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"ai", "application/postscript"},
            {"aif", "audio/x-aiff"},
            {"aifc", "audio/x-aiff"},
            {"aiff", "audio/x-aiff"},
            {"asc", "text/plain"},
            {"atom", "application/atom+xml"},
            {"au", "audio/basic"},
            {"avi", "video/x-msvideo"},
            {"bcpio", "application/x-bcpio"},
            {"bin", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"bmp", "image/bmp"},
            {"cdf", "application/x-netcdf"},
            {"cgm", "image/cgm"},
            {"class", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"cpio", "application/x-cpio"},
            {"cpt", "application/mac-compactpro"},
            {"csh", "application/x-csh"},
            {"css", "text/css"},
            {"dcr", "application/x-director"},
            {"dif", "video/x-dv"},
            {"dir", "application/x-director"},
            {"djv", "image/vnd.djvu"},
            {"djvu", "image/vnd.djvu"},
            {"dll", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"dmg", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"dms", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"doc", "application/msword"},
            {"docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
            {"dotx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"},
            {"docm", "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"dotm", "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"dtd", "application/xml-dtd"},
            {"dv", "video/x-dv"},
            {"dvi", "application/x-dvi"},
            {"dxr", "application/x-director"},
            {"eps", "application/postscript"},
            {"etx", "text/x-setext"},
            {"exe", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"ez", "application/andrew-inset"},
            {"gif", "image/gif"},
            {"gram", "application/srgs"},
            {"grxml", "application/srgs+xml"},
            {"gtar", "application/x-gtar"},
            {"hdf", "application/x-hdf"},
            {"hqx", "application/mac-binhex40"},
            {"htc", "text/x-component"},
            {"htm", "text/html"},
            {"html", "text/html"},
            {"ice", "x-conference/x-cooltalk"},
            {"ico", "image/x-icon"},
            {"ics", "text/calendar"},
            {"ief", "image/ief"},
            {"ifb", "text/calendar"},
            {"iges", "model/iges"},
            {"igs", "model/iges"},
            {"jnlp", "application/x-java-jnlp-file"},
            {"jp2", "image/jp2"},
            {"jpe", "image/jpeg"},
            {"jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
            {"jpg", "image/jpeg"},
            {"js", "application/x-javascript"},
            {"kar", "audio/midi"},
            {"latex", "application/x-latex"},
            {"lha", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"lzh", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"m3u", "audio/x-mpegurl"},
            {"m4a", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {"m4b", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {"m4p", "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {"m4u", "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
            {"m4v", "video/x-m4v"},
            {"mac", "image/x-macpaint"},
            {"man", "application/x-troff-man"},
            {"mathml", "application/mathml+xml"},
            {"me", "application/x-troff-me"},
            {"mesh", "model/mesh"},
            {"mid", "audio/midi"},
            {"midi", "audio/midi"},
            {"mif", "application/vnd.mif"},
            {"mov", "video/quicktime"},
            {"movie", "video/x-sgi-movie"},
            {"mp2", "audio/mpeg"},
            {"mp3", "audio/mpeg"},
            {"mp4", "video/mp4"},
            {"mpe", "video/mpeg"},
            {"mpeg", "video/mpeg"},
            {"mpg", "video/mpeg"},
            {"mpga", "audio/mpeg"},
            {"ms", "application/x-troff-ms"},
            {"msh", "model/mesh"},
            {"mxu", "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
            {"nc", "application/x-netcdf"},
            {"oda", "application/oda"},
            {"ogg", "application/ogg"},
            {"pbm", "image/x-portable-bitmap"},
            {"pct", "image/pict"},
            {"pdb", "chemical/x-pdb"},
            {"pdf", "application/pdf"},
            {"pgm", "image/x-portable-graymap"},
            {"pgn", "application/x-chess-pgn"},
            {"pic", "image/pict"},
            {"pict", "image/pict"},
            {"png", "image/png"},
            {"pnm", "image/x-portable-anymap"},
            {"pnt", "image/x-macpaint"},
            {"pntg", "image/x-macpaint"},
            {"ppm", "image/x-portable-pixmap"},
            {"ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"},
            {"pptx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"},
            {"potx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template"},
            {"ppsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow"},
            {"ppam", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"pptm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"potm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"ppsm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"ps", "application/postscript"},
            {"qt", "video/quicktime"},
            {"qti", "image/x-quicktime"},
            {"qtif", "image/x-quicktime"},
            {"ra", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
            {"ram", "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
            {"ras", "image/x-cmu-raster"},
            {"rdf", "application/rdf+xml"},
            {"rgb", "image/x-rgb"},
            {"rm", "application/vnd.rn-realmedia"},
            {"roff", "application/x-troff"},
            {"rtf", "text/rtf"},
            {"rtx", "text/richtext"},
            {"sgm", "text/sgml"},
            {"sgml", "text/sgml"},
            {"sh", "application/x-sh"},
            {"shar", "application/x-shar"},
            {"silo", "model/mesh"},
            {"sit", "application/x-stuffit"},
            {"skd", "application/x-koan"},
            {"skm", "application/x-koan"},
            {"skp", "application/x-koan"},
            {"skt", "application/x-koan"},
            {"smi", "application/smil"},
            {"smil", "application/smil"},
            {"snd", "audio/basic"},
            {"so", "application/octet-stream"},
            {"spl", "application/x-futuresplash"},
            {"src", "application/x-wais-source"},
            {"sv4cpio", "application/x-sv4cpio"},
            {"sv4crc", "application/x-sv4crc"},
            {"svg", "image/svg+xml"},
            {"swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash"},
            {"t", "application/x-troff"},
            {"tar", "application/x-tar"},
            {"tcl", "application/x-tcl"},
            {"tex", "application/x-tex"},
            {"texi", "application/x-texinfo"},
            {"texinfo", "application/x-texinfo"},
            {"tif", "image/tiff"},
            {"tiff", "image/tiff"},
            {"tr", "application/x-troff"},
            {"tsv", "text/tab-separated-values"},
            {"txt", "text/plain"},
            {"ustar", "application/x-ustar"},
            {"vcd", "application/x-cdlink"},
            {"vrml", "model/vrml"},
            {"vxml", "application/voicexml+xml"},
            {"wav", "audio/x-wav"},
            {"wbmp", "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"},
            {"wbmxl", "application/vnd.wap.wbxml"},
            {"wml", "text/vnd.wap.wml"},
            {"wmlc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlc"},
            {"wmls", "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript"},
            {"wmlsc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc"},
            {"wrl", "model/vrml"},
            {"xbm", "image/x-xbitmap"},
            {"xht", "application/xhtml+xml"},
            {"xhtml", "application/xhtml+xml"},
            {"xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
            {"xml", "application/xml"},
            {"xpm", "image/x-xpixmap"},
            {"xsl", "application/xml"},
            {"xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
            {"xltx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template"},
            {"xlsm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xltm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xlam", "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xlsb", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"},
            {"xslt", "application/xslt+xml"},
            {"xul", "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml"},
            {"xwd", "image/x-xwindowdump"},
            {"xyz", "chemical/x-xyz"},
            {"zip", "application/zip"}
        };
}
```

Comment: I will honestly appreciate any comment on the down vote - I really want to learn about any potential wrongdoing of this code.

Comment: I don't see any try-catch block in your code when you use the GetMimeTypeFromFileInternal. So, looks like that by default you just check the file extension, which is not really helpful if you are not sure, what is actually inside the file. And I still can't get, does the GetMimeTypeFromFileInternal work in Azure with Limited Trust? If not, then why it is still in the code?

Comment: In the case of a limited execution context, you can limit the code to use only the list. Yes, there are more extensions than that, but only the developer knows the context of the application and can add more to the list. And a try-catch is good addition that is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Winista MimeDetector from Netomatix. The sources can be downloaded for free after you created an account: http://www.netomatix.com/Products/DocumentManagement/MimeDetector.aspx

```
MimeTypes g_MimeTypes = new MimeTypes("mime-types.xml");
sbyte [] fileData = null;

using (System.IO.FileStream srcFile = new System.IO.FileStream(strFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    byte [] data = new byte[srcFile.Length];
    srcFile.Read(data, 0, (Int32)srcFile.Length);
    fileData = Winista.Mime.SupportUtil.ToSByteArray(data);
}

MimeType oMimeType = g_MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileData);
```

This is part of another question answered here: [Alternative to FindMimeFromData method in Urlmon.dll one which has more MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300567/alternative-to-findmimefromdata-method-in-urlmon-dll-one-which-has-more-mime-typ/15595571#15595571)
The best solution to this problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I found several problems of running this code:

```
UInt32 mimetype;
FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
```

If you will try to run it with x64/Win10 you will get

```
AccessViolationException "Attempted to read or write protected memory.
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"
```

Thanks to this post [PtrToStringUni doesnt work in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037460/ptrtostringuni-doesnt-work-in-windows-10) and @xanatos

I modified my solution to run under x64 and .NET Core 2.1:

```
   [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, 
    SetLastError = false)]
    static extern int FindMimeFromData(IntPtr pBC,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzUrl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I1, 
        SizeParamIndex=3)]
        byte[] pBuffer,
        int cbSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzMimeProposed,
        int dwMimeFlags,
        out IntPtr ppwzMimeOut,
        int dwReserved);

   string getMimeFromFile(byte[] fileSource)
   {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileSource))
            {
                if (stream.Length >= 256)
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
                else
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            }

            try
            {
                IntPtr mimeTypePtr;
                FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, null, buffer, buffer.Length,
                    null, 0, out mimeTypePtr, 0);

                string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
                return mime;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "unknown/unknown";
            }
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have adapted Winista.MimeDetect project into .net core/framework with fallback into urlmon.dll Fell free to use it: [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Winista.MimeDetect).

```
   //init
   var mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();

   //usage by filepath
   var mimeType1 = mimeTypes.GetMimeTypeFromFile(filePath);
```

Comment: gihub code sample is wrong here https://github.com/GetoXs/MimeDetect  . no overload `mimeTypes.GetMimeTypeFromFile(bytes);`