# What are the MIME types for .NET project source code files?

Tags: svn, content-type, mime-types, mod-dav-svn

Are there official MIME types for the .cs (C# source), .resx, .aspx, etc. files in a .NET project?

If no official types are defined, any recommendations on good MIME types? This will be exposed via Apache and the `mod_dav_svn` module when viewing a Subversion repository from a web browser, so anything that'll help Firefox *et al* render the file correctly would do the trick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the information on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/in-c-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature-not-t#58514) to easily determine the MIME types.

For example (running on Windows XP SP2) I got the following results:

- **cs** - text/plain
- **resx** - text/xml

Comment: Great answer - specific answers to specific questions, and general info on how to find out more. Thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Gnome uses text/x-csharp for C# source files, but I'd personally expect .cs and .aspx files to be text/plain and .resx to be text/xml.