# Is there a MIME type for C# (.cs) files?

Tags: mime-types

Standard UNIX tools (file command) return `text/x-c++`. This is not the greatest result possible.

On Windows [urlmon.dll/FindMimeFromData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `text/plain`. Looks like Windows never got any decent file type recognition library.

Is there something more precise than `text/plain`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the MIME types for .NET project source code files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208056/what-are-the-mime-types-for-net-project-source-code-files)

Comment: I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208060/282105) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17619050/282105) the "text/x-csharp" value is sometimes used but can't get a valid source for it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing on Ubuntu 20.04 - open .CS files in Code and other text files in the default editor.

I copied the line form the /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

```
text/plain=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
```

and added the .cs extension like so

```
text/plain.cs=code
```

Now my CS files open in VS Code and all other plain text files open in the default editor

Comment: Is this part of the MIME standards? Or part of the specialized `defaults.list` file format?