# How to view C# .cs file in google drive?

Tags: text-files, mime-types, google-drive-api, file-type

I have some .cs c# source code files in my google drive that I'd like to be able to view directly without having to download them.  How can I do this?  And in general, when there is a text file with a non-supported file extension how can I view this as text from google drive?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately many code file types are not supported yet. [From the support docs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423485?hl=en&topic=2375192&ctx=topic#)

.txt is supported but there is no way to view a file `as` some other type other than the underlying mime type that is assigned on upload. In the case of C# the mime type is `text/x-csharp`. This means that changing the extension of the file will not help either because that will not modify the mime type. (Tried it. No go.)

From the Google help docs:

**Google Drive lets you view these file types:**

```
Image files (.JPEG, .PNG, .GIF, .TIFF, .BMP)
Video files (WebM, .MPEG4, .3GPP, .MOV, .AVI, .MPEGPS, .WMV, .FLV)
Text files (.TXT)
Markup/Code (.CSS, .HTML, .PHP, .C, .CPP, .H, .HPP, .JS)
Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
Apple Pages (.PAGES)
Adobe Illustrator (.AI)
Adobe Photoshop (.PSD)
Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
TrueType (.TTF)
XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
Archive file types (.ZIP and .RAR)
```

It would be nice if Google support other languages in a addition to the handful they have but a real simple fix would be to allow a plain text viewing on mime types matching `text/*`. There are lots of requests on for these kinds of features on various message boards but I didn't see anything that would make it look like Google's going to oblige.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a Google Drive App that will let you see c# files, its called Neutron Drive. Not sure how functional as I am just trying out, though it does have code highlighting.

Comment: It's gone, unless you have a link