# How can I determine that a particular file is in fact an MP3 file?

Tags: c#

How can I determine that a particular file (which may or may not have an ".mp3" file extension) is in fact an MP3 file? I wish to do this in C#.

Comment: C# and file type magic numbers; possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654846/in-c-how-can-i-know-the-file-type-from-a-byte

Comment: If you successfully load it using the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/, you might consider it a valid MP3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. using file extension is not reliable.
2. the best libary you can use is https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp it detects most of the common file types. maybe you just want mp3, so you can extract any mp3 related class.
3. a simpler library you can use is https://github.com/judwhite/IdSharp

Answer (score 17):

According to http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html an mp3 file will always start with ID3 (hex 49 44 33) However, presence of these bytes only mean that the file is tagged with [ID3 information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3).  If this signature is not found, it could be an untagged mp3 file.  To determine this, check out [the mp3 file structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure) and you'll see that an mp3 frame starts with the signature ff fb (hex).

So :

- if file starts with hex `49 44 33`

or

- if file starts with hex `ff fb`

it's safe to assume that it's an MP3.

Answer (score 5):

Files often start with a "magic number" to identify the data format. Depending on the format, a file starts with a certain sequence of bytes which is unique to that format. There's no standard to follow so it's not 100% reliable.

As fvu says, the mp3 magic number is `0x49 0x44 0x33`

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(fbdialog.SelectedPath.ToString(),".mp3", 
                                       SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string str in filePath)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's mp3 file");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

C# code:

```
bool isMP3(byte[] buf)
{
    if (buf[0] == 0xFF && (buf[1] & 0xF6) > 0xF0 && (buf[2] & 0xF0) != 0xF0) 
    {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```