# Determining file extension given a FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream, file-extension

Is there any way to know the type of the `FileStream`. I have a function that takes a `FileStream` object and I want to determine the file extension based on that `FileStream`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 string extension = Path.GetExtension(myFileStream.Name);
```

Answer (score 24):

If the stream is really a `FileStream` then you should be able to do the following

```
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileStream.Name);
```

If it's a plain old `Stream` though then it's not generally possible to get the extension because a `Stream` can be created for any stream of bytes.  It doesn't have to have a backing file.

**Update**

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231316/chris-haas) pointed out in the comments there is another SO question which is relevant to this discussion.  It's discussing heuristics for determining type of a `byte[]` which can then be mapped to a *probable* original signature.

- [In C#, how can I know the file type from a byte[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654846/in-c-how-can-i-know-the-file-type-from-a-byte)

It's by no means foolproof but may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using the file name the following will return `.txt` (including the `.`):

```
var path = myFileStream.Name;
return Path.GetExtension(path);
```