# Determining .exe file in time of upload

Tags: asp.net

I have developed File Upload web page in ASP.NET. Now user can rename a .exe file to txt or some other extension and upload the same. I want to restrict that. How I can implement that in ASP.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, how can I know the file type from a byte\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654846/in-c-how-can-i-know-the-file-type-from-a-byte)

Comment: This seems like a dicey proposition: If you examine the byte array, your users will start zipping them. When you start examining those zip files, they'll start password protecting their zip files. If you disallow them completely, they'll find some other novel way. There's many tricks to get around this kind of restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way to do this is to get the `byte []` from the file that has been posted and examine it to determine if the file is indeed in one of the formats you allow the user to upload. You don't need to save the file, you can just get the `byte[]` from the `HttpPostedFile` object.

Other than examining the content ([looking for magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), for example) there isn't an infallible way to make sure that the user is not attempting to upload something that you don't allow.