# How can I determine the type of a file in C# when I'm missing the extension? (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard

I'm developing a Xamarin app and there are cases where I have to interact with files from other apps. 
I'm working with files which have a filename like `example.txt.xyz` because another app appended `.xyz` to the filename. Unfortunately, many Android apps such as Samsungs E-Mail don't give me the full filename when they pass a file but instead pass `RAW` as the filename.

Is there a way in `.net standard`, C#, Xamarin or Android where I can still figure out the true filetype (.txt in the above example)?

Given that I'm within Xamarin I don't have access to the full .net functions and can't rely on Internet Explorer as done in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654846/in-c-how-can-i-know-the-file-type-from-a-byte).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, how can I know the file type from a byte\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654846/in-c-how-can-i-know-the-file-type-from-a-byte)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886866/how-to-find-the-extension-of-a-file

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature) might help, you need to know the mime-type of the file