# Base64 Validation For Audio

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, audio, base64

Actually, I want to receive base64 in API but I want to allow base64 which **contain only Audio** following is the function by which I validate base64 but before `Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);` I want to validate that this base64 is audio.

```
public static int CheckAudio(string base64String)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String) || base64String.Length % 4 != 0
               || base64String.Contains(" ") || base64String.Contains("\t") || base64String.Contains("\r") || base64String.Contains("\n"))
                return (int)ConfezzStatusCode.InValidParamter;

            try
            {
                 Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
                    return (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            catch
            {
                // Handle the exception
                return (int)ConfezzStatusCode.InValidParamter;
            }
        }
```

**Note: I want to allow only Audio files.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) to detect if it is a known audio format. Something like this:

```
// Decode the whole string to make sure it is a valid Base64
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

// Just for readability store it as HEX
// You might want to store only the file header (eg, 64 bytes)
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);

if (hex.StartsWith("49-44-33"))
{
  Console.WriteLine("mp3");
}
else if (hex.StartsWith("66-4C-61-43"))
{
  Console.WriteLine("flac");
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("unknown:" + hex);
}
```

For more thoughts check:

- [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)
- [In C#, how can I know the file type from a byte[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654846/in-c-how-can-i-know-the-file-type-from-a-byte)