# "Attempted to read or write protected memory" caused by urlmon.dll

Tags: c#, iis, urlmon

I know this has been asked many times but unfortunately I haven't find a solution to my problem, I'm using `urlmon.dll` to find the MIME type from array of bytes but I receive a crash by the IIS process `w3wp.exe`

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The code:

```
public static int MimeSampleSize = 256;

public static string DefaultMimeType = "application/octet-stream";

[DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static uint FindMimeFromData(
    uint pBC,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pwzUrl,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
    uint cbSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pwzMimeProposed,
    uint dwMimeFlags,
    out uint ppwzMimeOut,
    uint dwReserverd
);

public static string GetMimeFromBytes(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        uint mimeType;
        FindMimeFromData(0, null, data, (uint)MimeSampleSize, null, 0, out mimeType, 0);

        var mimePointer = new IntPtr(mimeType);
        var mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimePointer); // <-- Crash happens here
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimePointer);

        return mime ?? DefaultMimeType;
    }
    catch
    {
        return DefaultMimeType;
    }
}
```

The crash happens right on the following line:

```
var mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimePointer);
```

I have tried to uncheck the "`Suppress JIT optimization on module load`" option with no luck.
Also tried to change the build to x86 instead of Any CPU without any luck.

*Note*: I'm using 4.5 framework, IIS 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is the signature of FindMimeFromData(). Look here at PInvoke.net for correct signature of the function:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/findmimefromdata.html

..so instead of uint for pBC and ppwzMimeOut you will need IntPtr!

See also:

[urlmon.dll FindMimeFromData() works perfectly on 64bit desktop/console but generates errors on ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358548/urlmon-dll-findmimefromdata-works-perfectly-on-64bit-desktop-console-but-gener)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I had to use this today and it worked perfectly.