# Can I filter which type of document (ex just pdf) to load in a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, browser

I have a  System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control on my form, how can i load just pdf files into it? Can i determine it before loading it to the browser control?

Comment: How / where are you loading the files?

Comment: This smells a little bit like a hack. If all you want to be able to display is PDF files, why not use a dedicated PDF viewer control instead of a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Navigating event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx

If it is not a PDF (`application/pdf`), set `e.Cancel = true;` in the Navigating event.

<strike>Check the file extension using FileInfo.</strike>

**EDIT**

Get the file's MIME content type:

http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-get-mimetype-from-file-name.html

**EDIT**

If PDF files are local, check the MIME content type using:

[Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)

Comment: Extensions aren't reliable, especially in URLs.

Comment: True, the MIME content type is more reliable.

Comment: `c-get-mimetype-from-file-name` - Except the MIME content type is pulled from the filename extension.  :)  In this case it's an unnecessary wrapper.