# Modify WCF 4.0 REST Web Service Response

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm relatively new to WCF, specifically the WCF 4 REST Online Template.

I am testing a basic method:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test")]
public string Test() 
{
    return "Test";
}
```

The response generated is:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Hello World</string>
```

Is there any way to send back anything other than XML or JSON, or is there any way to modify the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `Stream`; WCF won't apply formatting and you would be free to write whatever content you wanted to the Stream.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221(VS.90).aspx) may help.

**Edit:**
Also, keep in mind that if you are going to use this method to serve up a file, for example, then  you'll need to find some way to set the MIME type appropriately. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature) should give you some ideas. Personally, I prefer the [Registry Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature/1685614#1685614) method suggested by @Serguei.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out. Does it make more sense to use MVC REST instead of WCF, seeing as how MVC gives you an easier way to control the response?

Comment: @XSaint32. I suppose it depends on taste. I prefer WCF REST for everything rather than MVC REST, but I work with a guy who's exactly the opposite. Our conversations get interesting. :) Also, I've edited my response with a caveat that you'll want to keep in mind if you go WCF.