# Why does the FindMimeFromData function from Urlmon.dll return MIME type “application/octet-stream” for many file types?

Tags: c#, .net, mime, mime-types

Why does the FindMimeFromData function from Urlmon.dll return MIME type “application/octet-stream” for many file types, whereas checking MIME type by file extension (I.e. against windows registry) returns a more precise type?

For example, mp3 is an “application/octet-stream” instead of “audio/mp3”.

Basically, I want to verify an uploaded file with incorrect extension. This method seems to work for many image files, xml, etc.

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature), but the provided solution is not suited for validating uploaded files, because of different/ambiguous MIME types returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the documentation for [FindMimeFromData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107(VS.85).aspx) lead me to [MIME Type Detection in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx). According to that information it is hard-coded to find [26 different MIME types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx#Known_MimeTypes), which is quite small in today's world. "audio/mp3" is not one of them.

> FindMimeFromData **contains hard-coded tests for (currently 26) separate MIME type** (see Known MIME Types). This means that if a given buffer contains data in the format of one of these MIME types, a test exists in FindMimeFromData that is designed (by scanning through the buffer contents) to recognize the corresponding MIME type. A MIME type is known if it is one of these N MIME types. A MIME type is ambiguous if it is "text/plain," "application/octet-stream," an empty string, or null (that is, the server failed to provide it).

Unfortunately, it looks like `FindMimeFromData` won't be very useful for determining modern MIME types.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435701/74585 which tries to determine the file type from the registry (by file extension?) if FindMimeFromData returns "application/octet-stream" "text/plain" or nothing at all.

Here's a .NET file type detecting library http://filetypedetective.codeplex.com/ but it only detects a smallish number of files at the moment.