# Proper use of Response.ContentType

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have a site that allows users to upload a document such as pdf, word, excel etc.

Now in my code, when I want to show the document in a browser, I am checking for the extension and setting the ContentType appropriately.

However, this switch statement just doesn't sound like the best solution.

Is there a way I can set the content type based on the `Stream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use switch like statements, use Dictionary to add possible `MIME`-entries.

```
Dictionary<string, string> map=new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"txt", "text/plain"},                                                
  {"exe", "application/octet-stream"},
  {"bmp", "image/bmp"}
};
```

and set content type,

```
Response.ContentType=map[ext];
```

I've found an interesting stackoverflow thread - [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)

Comment: AVD, thanks for this.  I guess by your answer then there is no real way to infer the type from either the byte array or the stream?

Comment: @griegs - Please check the link I've added.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I can't user Urlmon but based on your solution of a dictionary, I found this handy class.  https://github.com/cymen/ApacheMimeTypesToDotNet/blob/master/ApacheMimeTypes.cs