# How to reliably detect mime type of uploaded [text-based] file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mime-types

My site allows for resume upload, but I want to make sure users won't be uploading anything else but plain text, rtf or word documents (both old *.doc and new *.docx formats). Obviously I can't go entirely by extension, I need to somehow detect file's mime type by its content. Any ideas how to reliably do that for the above types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of the [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature) question here on stackoverflow. This one includes an answer with a code sample to use the FindMimeFromData method from urlmon.dll.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will send you a mime type when the file is uploaded.  While not 100% consistent or reliable, that might be your best bet.