# File Format check while File upload in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

While File Upload i have checked the following thing

```
   if !(strExtension == ".jpg" || strExtension == ".jpeg" || strExtension == ".pdf" || strExtension == ".png")

   Send Error
```

This is working fine,

But i have one issue ,if someone uploads a xlsx file by just changing its extension as jpg my uploader will not obstruct it and the file will be saved which is orginally an xlsx file

How do i check the file origin. without its extension.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check a file type when there is no extension in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747278/how-do-you-check-a-file-type-when-there-is-no-extension-in-c-sharp)

Comment: [blog]: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature/58570#58570

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature/58570#58570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just use [Mime Detective](https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective)

I use byte array sequences to determine the correct MIME type of a given file. The advantage of this over just looking at the file extension of the file name is that if a user were to rename a file to bypass certain file type upload restrictions, the file name extension would fail to catch this. On the other hand, getting the file signature via byte array will stop this mischievous behavior from happening.

Here is an example in C#:

```
public class MimeType
{
    private static readonly byte[] BMP = { 66, 77 };
    private static readonly byte[] DOC = { 208, 207, 17, 224, 161, 177, 26, 225 };
    private static readonly byte[] EXE_DLL = { 77, 90 };
    private static readonly byte[] GIF = { 71, 73, 70, 56 };
    private static readonly byte[] ICO = { 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] JPG = { 255, 216, 255 };
    private static readonly byte[] MP3 = { 255, 251, 48 };
    private static readonly byte[] OGG = { 79, 103, 103, 83, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] PDF = { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46 };
    private static readonly byte[] PNG = { 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82 };
    private static readonly byte[] RAR = { 82, 97, 114, 33, 26, 7, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] SWF = { 70, 87, 83 };
    private static readonly byte[] TIFF = { 73, 73, 42, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] TORRENT = { 100, 56, 58, 97, 110, 110, 111, 117, 110, 99, 101 };
    private static readonly byte[] TTF = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] WAV_AVI = { 82, 73, 70, 70 };
    private static readonly byte[] WMV_WMA = { 48, 38, 178, 117, 142, 102, 207, 17, 166, 217, 0, 170, 0, 98, 206, 108 };
    private static readonly byte[] ZIP_DOCX = { 80, 75, 3, 4 };

    public static string GetMimeType(byte[] file, string fileName)
    {

        string mime = "application/octet-stream"; //DEFAULT UNKNOWN MIME TYPE

        //Ensure that the filename isn't empty or null
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            return mime;
        }

        //Get the file extension
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName) == null
                               ? string.Empty
                               : Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpper();

        //Get the MIME Type
        if (file.Take(2).SequenceEqual(BMP))
        {
            mime = "image/bmp";
        }
        else if (file.Take(8).SequenceEqual(DOC))
        {
            mime = "application/msword";
        }
        else if (file.Take(2).SequenceEqual(EXE_DLL))
        {
            mime = "application/x-msdownload"; //both use same mime type
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(GIF))
        {
            mime = "image/gif";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(ICO))
        {
            mime = "image/x-icon";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(JPG))
        {
            mime = "image/jpeg";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(MP3))
        {
            mime = "audio/mpeg";
        }
        else if (file.Take(14).SequenceEqual(OGG))
        {
            if (extension == ".OGX")
            {
                mime = "application/ogg";
            }
            else if (extension == ".OGA")
            {
                mime = "audio/ogg";
            }
            else
            {
                mime = "video/ogg";
            }
        }
        else if (file.Take(7).SequenceEqual(PDF))
        {
            mime = "application/pdf";
        }
        else if (file.Take(16).SequenceEqual(PNG))
        {
            mime = "image/png";
        }
        else if (file.Take(7).SequenceEqual(RAR))
        {
            mime = "application/x-rar-compressed";
        }
        else if (file.Take(3).SequenceEqual(SWF))
        {
            mime = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(TIFF))
        {
            mime = "image/tiff";
        }
        else if (file.Take(11).SequenceEqual(TORRENT))
        {
            mime = "application/x-bittorrent";
        }
        else if (file.Take(5).SequenceEqual(TTF))
        {
            mime = "application/x-font-ttf";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(WAV_AVI))
        {
            mime = extension == ".AVI" ? "video/x-msvideo" : "audio/x-wav";
        }
        else if (file.Take(16).SequenceEqual(WMV_WMA))
        {
            mime = extension == ".WMA" ? "audio/x-ms-wma" : "video/x-ms-wmv";
        }
        else if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(ZIP_DOCX))
        {
            mime = extension == ".DOCX" ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/x-zip-compressed";
        }

        return mime;
    }


}
```

Notice I handled DOCX file types differently since DOCX is really just a ZIP file. In this scenario, I simply check the file extension once I verified that it has that sequence. This example is far from complete for some people, but you can easily add your own.

If you want to add more MIME types, you can get the byte array sequences of many different file types [from here](http://www.mircscripts.org/showdoc.php?type=code&id=2933). Also, [here is another good resource](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) concerning file signatures.

What I do a lot of times if all else fails is step through several files of a particular type that I am looking for and look for a pattern in the byte sequence of the files. In the end, this is still basic verification and cannot be used for 100% proof of determining file types.

Comment: What to do for xlsx

Comment: @RohitShetty you can figure out type header by your self. Just convert a file with .xlsx (or any extension you need) to a byte array. Perform this operation for a bunch of diffrent files and figure out a chain of bytes that is not changed. It will be a header which is a type marker.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I am going to share my solution of **validator**

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, byte[]> _mimeTypes = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>
{
    {"image/jpeg", new byte[] {255, 216, 255}},
    {"image/jpg", new byte[] {255, 216, 255}},
    {"image/pjpeg", new byte[] {255, 216, 255}},
    {"image/apng", new byte[] {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82}},
    {"image/png", new byte[] {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82}},
    {"image/bmp", new byte[] {66, 77}},
    {"image/gif", new byte[] {71, 73, 70, 56}},
};

private bool ValidateMimeType(byte[] file, string contentType)
{
    var imageType = _mimeTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(contentType));

    return file.Take(imageType.Value.Length).SequenceEqual(imageType.Value);
}
```