# Get extension from a file which is has not extension

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

is there any method to get (actually guess!) the extension file?
in my program, somewhere I get a file which the application analyze it for understanding is it ZIP or MOV.

I found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747278/how-do-you-check-a-file-type-when-there-is-no-extension-in-c-sharp), but it does not support MOV and ZIP.

**Update:**

By creating a text file which contains the first 8 bits of the file signatures.
and the below code, I can determine every file which has no extension.
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures.) page could be a good reference.

```
        string rootPath = $"{name}";
        using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(rootPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[8]; // the number of bytes you want to read
            fsSource.Read(fileBytes, 0, 8);

            /*
             zip = 50-4B-03-04-0A-00-00-00
             mov = 00-00-00-20-66-74-79-70
             html = 3C-21-64-6F-63-74-79-70
             rar 1 = 52-61-72-21-1A-07
             rar 5 = 52-61-72-21-1A-07 

            */
            string filestring = BitConverter.ToString(fileBytes);
            // string filestring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes); 
            File.WriteAllText($"{DownloadPath}\\filestring.txt", filestring);
        }
```

Comment: Read up on those file formats. Then open the files and examine the structure to figure out the type.

Comment: A file extension is just some text.  Do you actually mean the file type?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, exactly what I mean!

Comment: @Adriani6 It's actually not uncommon at all, especially for files in Unix or from programs heavily associated with Unix.

Comment: A file does not have to have an extension. You can check its header to determine its type. Formats like ZIP and MOV are well defined, you can find their header info on the internet.

Comment: [This could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)

Comment: @mason Yup, had to look it up. It all makes sense :)

Comment: @Sinatr It does not support MOV and zip files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read the header section of the file (several bytes at the beginning of the file) and you can detect its format.

For example [this page](http://www.file-recovery.com/mov-signature-format.htm) has information about mov files.

You can read file header like this code (here I have assumed that reading 4 bytes will be enough, however, you can change it as you like if you need more/less bytes to determine the format):

```
 using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
     byte[] bytes = new byte[4]; // the number of bytes you want to read
     fsSource.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, actually it is yours! and I just want to fix its bugs!

Comment: what about `4-letter` extension files?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto, we are not talking about extensions here, we open the file and read 4 (in here) first bytes of the file and determine if the file extension should be mov, zip, or something else

Comment: I missread. Good solution.My apologies

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto You are very welcome.