# How Can I get Mime Type in IOS which is not based on extension

Tags: ios, stream, mime-types

we know that we can get the file's MIME TYPE from the file's extension,but it's not exactly.for example we changed the file's extension and we will get the wrong mime type.
and also we know the way that get the mime type by a file signature in C#,(using the urlmon.dll [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature).But) ,my question is that how can we get the exact mime type in IOS,no matter the file's extension is changed by someone,we can getthe right mime type.

thank you for your attention~!

Comment: There is no such concept as a `file signature` on iOS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Would you tell me how I get the right mime type exactly when I get a path of a file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Would you tell me how I get the right mime type exactly when I get a
>   path of a file.

iOS uses the concept of [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE) (UTI) to handle document types.

```
NSString *path; // contains the file path

// Get the UTI from the file's extension:

CFStringRef pathExtension = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
CFStringRef type = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension, NULL);
CFRelease(pathExtension);

// The UTI can be converted to a mime type:

NSString *mimeType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(type, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
if (type != NULL)
    CFRelease(type);
```

You should consider using UTIs for your purpose directly instead of converting them to the less powerful mime type.

Comment: it won't give correct mimetype. It's not even checking actual file. It's just translating **extension to mimetype**

Comment: @Johnnywho This answer is about getting the mime type **from  a path** (as stated explicitly and was requested by the OP in a comment).

Comment: But original question with its title regards the mime type **not based** on the extension. In that way, your answer is misleading and I wasted my time trying your code. You should state explicitly that the path must've an extension. None part of your answer is saying that.

Comment: I know this is an old discussion, but I came across it just now through Google, and it was helpful. Note that you also need: `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`, and to add the MobileCoreServices framework, to make it work.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe why not use `__bridge` instead of `__bridge_retained`? if you use `__bridge`, the `CFRelease(pathExtension)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @oldman That would mean that the temporary object returned from `pathExtension` would have no explicit strong reference but being used after. I'm not sure about the guarantees ARC gives when using a derived pointer (the `CFStringRef`) about the lifetime of the bridged object.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe you can use `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge)[path pathExtension], NULL);` ^_^

Comment: Anyone figured this out in Swift yet?

Comment: OP asked for a mime type NOT based on extension.