# iOS determining how to open file

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I'm developing an app where people can download files, and have no problem downloading and saving them. The problem is, when some files are downloaded, they have no file extension (`http://test.com/test`, instead of `http://test.com/test.zip`), and I can't determine what kind of file they are. I've tried using `NSHTTPURLResponse`'s `suggestedFilename` property, but that still doesn't put an extension on the file. So my question is, how do I know what kind of file something is without an extension? I've also tried [getting the mime type of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401918/1702077), but that didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you are downloading the file using `NSURLConnection`, have you tried getting the file's mime type from the response's `MIMType`?

Comment: What didn't work about getting the MIME type? That's how browsers do it, regardless of the file extension. Edit: actually, here's the iOS way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801106/how-can-i-get-mime-type-in-ios-which-is-not-based-on-extension Second edit: never mind, that just uses the file extension. Stick to MIME type :)