# Unknown mimetype MFMailComposerViewController

Tags: mime-types, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application a document file is downloading from the server and it is attaching to the MFMailcomposeViewOntroller but the document may be .pdf/.doc/.docx/.txt/.excel etc 
my problem is how to set the attachment mime ttype im mailcomposer?

Apple doc sayes mime type must not be nil
How can I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the class reference for the MFMailComposerViewController, especially the method `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Check this post on how to get the mime type based on the extension of a file: [How Can I get Mime Type in IOS which is not based on extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801106/how-can-i-get-mime-type-in-ios-which-is-not-based-on-extension)