# How do I get a document UTI from a file path?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, uti

I have a document path as an `NSString`.  How do I get its [UTI](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) as an `NSString`?  I currently use `LSCopyItemAttribute` but that requires an `FSRef` and all the functions for making an `FSRef` seems to be deprecated.

(Note: This is for Mac OS 10.8+.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to get it using mobile core services framework. Refer the code below

```
NSString *path; // contains the file path

// Get the UTI from the file's extension:

CFStringRef pathExtension = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
CFStringRef type = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension, NULL);
CFRelease(pathExtension);
```

The code snippet is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802467/641062).

Comment: Thanks Vignesh - that looks like it should work - I will try it this afternoon and check your answer. I should have mentioned this is for Mac OS but the same function is in CoreServices Mac OS. If a file has no extension is it possible to get its UTI?

Comment: This should work with Mac OS as well. I haven't tried though. This is merely mapping UTI's for path extension. Without extension some sort of file content look up would be needed. I don't know how to do it. I will look for it , if I find something useful I will update the post.

Comment: Hi Vignesh - I found this: `[inUrl getResourceValue:&uti forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey error:&error];` which lets me get the UTI without using core foundation.  Seems to be equivalent, no?

Comment: @MikeT, Yes. It definitely seems equivalent. More appropriate perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Use can use `url.resourceValues(forKeys:` (as mentioned in the comments):

```
if let resourceValues = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]),
    let uti = resourceValues.typeIdentifier {
    return uti
}
```

Comment: There is a difference in behaviour between the answers... 

This method getResourceValue:forKey:error: only works for File urls that exist. It gives an error if the file does not exist. 

The other answer using UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag works just using the file extension without needing a physical file.