# Check if a file URI is HTML or not in the WebClient class

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am downloading a file with the WebClient class, but sometimes the file returns as HTML (I can't do anything about this) What I would like to do is check whether the content is HTML or not using the WebClient class, my code is as follows:

```
client.DownloadFile(downloadURL, "downloadedfile.zip");
```

Comment: You should probably set AutoRedirect to false in which case you will be able to know if file doesn;t exist or other error cases.. I guess webclient doesnt have this property but other classes should have it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use UrlMon:

- [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)

Another might WebResponse.ContentType:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.contenttype%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I believe the latter is simply part of the WebClient response headers:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx

Try whichever looks most promising, and let us know what you find!