# Is there a library that gets the media type and subtype out of a HttpWebResponse/WebResponse ContentType?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, content-type

The [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.contenttype.aspx) property of ([Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx))[WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) maps to the HTTP/1.1 [Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.17) which is a [Media-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.7) that contains a `type`/`subtype` optionally followed by parameters which are [attribute=value pairs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6).

I'm mainly interested in the `type`/`subtype` and the [charset](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.4) parameter.

The `charset` is mapped from [HttpWebRequest.CharacterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.characterset.aspx).

Is there a library that just retrieves the media `type`/`subtype` of the [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contenttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: it may helps to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature

Comment: For now I'm just looking at something that dissects the `ContentType`. In the future I might use that in the future if I find out that the returned data does not match the `ContentType`.