# Is it possible to get the file extension or type from a file loaded into MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am creating a service in C# that is to be used by an ASP.Net Web API that will process and store files.

As part of the Web API I take the file(s) and store them in `MemoryStream`s which are then passed through to a service for actual processing and storage.

Part of the service will be to generate a new filename for each of the files.

so that leads me to the question, is it possible to find out what file type/extension the file was now that it's in a MemoryStream?

Comment: Why don't you store that info somewhere while loading these files, instead of trying to *guess*?

Comment: The file type/extension will have to come as a parameter with the file bytes.  File type/extension is a purely subjective thing.  Short of actually analyzing the bytes compared to known file formats, there is no way to tell.

Comment: Yes @EZI , that is an option I had thought about; get the extension and stream at the same time and pass them both into the service. I wasn't sure if it could be ascertained from the MemoryStream somehow; then there would be no 'guessing'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No for extension, you can guess type:

Unless content of the file somehow contains name/extension `MemoryStream` by itself does not contain any information about original file name.

You may try to detect type of the file (many formats have [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)/[signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) in the beginning for example) by reading some/all content of the stream.

There are also several similar questions like [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature) (discusses usage of UrlMon to detect type).

Comment: Thanks for the links. That's the sort of thing i was looking for - looks to be more of a pain that just passing it along in the first place i guess.

Comment: @Darren yes... If you can ask for file type and *don't have to validate it* than asking caller to provide file type is easier and more reliable option.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to examine the data and see what content type it is based on characteristics of the content types you expect to handle. A better solution would be to capture that information as part of the process when you load the file, and pass it along with it.

To capture that information, either assume that the file extension tells you what type it is, or have the user (or calling code) select from a list of valid file types.

[This post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data) might be useful, they discuss detecting file type based on the content.

Answer (score 2):

No, `MemoryStream` does not know or care where its bytes came from.

You can guess the file format from the first few bytes. I'm sure there is code available on the web to do this.

Or, just make the caller of your service transmit this information.