# SMS Message with Twilio and media using MediaUrl

Tags: twilio-api

I am submitting an SMS via [Twilio's SMS API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages/php) . Each time I try to send a message with the MediaUrl parameter I get the the following response:

> {
> "code": 21620,
> "message": "Invalid media URL(s)",
> "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21620",
> "status": 400
> }

I have tried using PostMan as well with the same results. It doesn't seem to like the way that the array is formatted even though it follows the same format of the Twilio documentation.

["https://somesite.com/media/HR/65-652943_banner-stock-cartoon-girls-clipart-cartoon-people-happy.png","https://somesite.com/media/HR/android-chrome-192x192.png"]

I have tried a single element array, wrapping the JSON string in single quotes, removing the brackets entirely, but no matter what I try It still tells me that I have an "Invlaid media URL(s)" [error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21620).

My Postman configuration is below.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqPzP.png)

I've tried using the option for x-www-form-urlencoded instead of form-data as well with the same results.

This should be a simple fix but I am just not seeing it. If anyone else can shed any light on the subject it would be much appreciated. I am using Coldfusion to make the API call but if I can figure this out through Postman I think I can get it going in CF.

Comment: Is the somesite.com address returning a valid mime-type? A web server might be returning application/octet-stream for binary data which is not support: https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/accepted-mime-types

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I have forced it to return the correct content-type and verified but I still get the same error.

Comment: Twilio can only do MMS to US or Canada phone numbers. Are you dialing a US or Canada phone number? Next question, can you open the URL in an browser window without authenticating (i.e. in an incognito window)? Is the HTTPS certificate valid? Not sure if you noticed but the first url mixes hyphen - with underscore _ in the url. Should it be 65-652943-banner-stock ...

Comment: Yes, the number I am testing with is a US number. All other texts that I send are received, it is only when I add the MediaUrl that I get the error. Yes, the URL is a public URL and I can access both of the images without authenticating. 

Here are the actual URLs to the images: 

[
    "https://portal.lindsey.edu/apps/raiderText/media/HR/65-652943_banner-stock-cartoon-girls-clipart-cartoon-people-happy.png",
    "https://portal.lindsey.edu/apps/raiderText/media/HR/android-chrome-192x192.png"
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test and was able to send the MMS using one of the images but one is causing an error.

This image (https://..../media/HR/65-652943_banner-stock-cartoon-girls-clipart-cartoon-people-happy.png) is generating an error [12300](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12300):

> Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL.
> Please see Twilio's documentation on accepted content types for more
> information on valid Content-Types.

According to this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670077/how-can-i-tell-if-an-extensionless-image-is-png-or-jpeg), the image isn't actually a png even though it has a .png file extension. I viewed the file in a hex editor and the first bytes aren't correct for a png.

Try opening the image in an image editor and re-saving as either a png or jpg then try sending again.

Comment: That was it! I edited the image and confirmed the change with a binary editor, resubmitted and it worked. 

I still have an issue sending more than one file at a time though. When the value is an array I get the 21620 error message. See my screenshot from Postman in my original post. 

If you have any insight on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @AnthonyMoore, glad it was helpful. To send an array in Postman just repeat the MediaUrl parameter. Postman may require you to label it as MediaUrl[0] = http://image1 and MediaUrl[1] = http://image2. I don't use Postman so I can't test it for you. The c# SDK is sending the same parameter "repeated" as MediaUrl = http://image1 and MediaUrl = http://image2 (without the array index parameter).