# How do I detect the data type inside byte array?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a byte[] array filled with data. I can't rely on the file extension (from which the array of data comes from) being a reliable indicator of the data type.

That being said, how can I "detect" the type of data that is stored in the byte array?

Comment: It will depend on how the data is stored in the byte[], if it is xml it might be easy to determine the datatype, if it is json it might be harder and if you used BinarySereialization it might be easy to deserialize it and then call .GetType() on the object

Comment: @DonaldJansen I am using: `FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path); Content = new byte[fileStream.Length]; fileStream.Read(Content, 0, Content.Length); fileStream.Close();` to embed the data. It's part of a larger class which stores objects as Serialized JSON files.

Comment: Well it's byes isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to read type from binary data.

Comment: Does your software also create your files ?

Comment: @DonaldJansen It does create the files as well. Well, on a case by case basis... Sometimes these files are "attached", meaning, sometimes the file could be an existing file the user has chosen to attach, which then gets converted to byte array then stored in JSON file.

Comment: use [FindMimeFromData](http://stackoverflow.com/a/62007/578411)

Comment: What you can then do is something like this, its a method I use to send data over a network.
4 bytes to specify the byte[] size, 4 bytes to specify an enum, x bytes (taken from the first 4 bytes to store the actual data)