# interpret byte array to determine the data inside

Tags: sql, .net, c#-4.0, bitmap, arrays

I'm new hire here,I've SQL database with bunch of tables. one specific table with 40-45 columns have a bitmap column with gigantic string(one single value in a cell).
I have a scenario to convert this bitmap data and see what actually it contains (its not a valid image for sure).
I browse many byte[]-array related articles available online but so far no help. Is there any way I can do this problem with WinForm or Console App as I don't have the complete or any part of the solution/project. I just have sql database.

```
     public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
      {
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
         imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
         return ms.ToArray();
      }

      public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
      {
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
          Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
          return returnImage;
         }
```

Also, It's a TIFF image document with a "Add Stamp" script/configuration,how to see this bitmap data?
and how to interpret the stamp/functionality part from this?

Read all this and many other resources.
[Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature/62007#62007)

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted an example data string, but this code might help. You could implement this in a C# console app for speed:

```
byte[] byteArr = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("image.tif");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("image.tif", byteArr);
```

Assume you have already imported the data string into `byteArr`.

Comment: benstopics Thank you for helping me out, Here's how I am reading data from db column(see code) where/how to create image.tif file or where is it coming from?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[3]);

Comment: Also keep getting parameter not valid exception                          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                        picturebox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);