# How to get mime type from file contents in a pure dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mime-types, mime

So far in .net I have been using urlmon.dll FindMimeFromData function which works really well and does not even require having full file contents present in a buffer (practically 1024 bytes is sufficient for most file types including XML).

Now in dotnet core although it's possible to use this native library I would like to avoid such dependencies and use a reliable native C# method to determine the file type (images in my case).

Is there any method of doing it without using native dependencies (Mime nuget project) or guessing just by filename (MimeSharp nuget project)?

Comment: Read `not accepted answers` in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature).

Comment: Most of these solutions resolve mime type by extension which is not reliable if detection involves a file provided by a user (web or desktop). The rest involves native calls (urlmon).