# How to get MIME types of files within zip file without extracting and saving them on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-core, zip

In an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app I have the ability to upload a ZIP file. The contents of the ZIP file are extracted and saved in a directory. However, before saving the files on the server, I want to check their MIME types (a.k.a. content-types) to ensure that none of them are potentially dangerous files to store, such as EXE. If the ZIP file contains an unwanted file, I'd like to just show a model error on the page.

I tried to loop through the files within the zip to check their MIME types after storing the ZIP file in the directory. With this method, while I can see the file name with extension, I can't see the MIME type. Going by the extension alone isn't a good idea because it can be spoofed.

```
Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.zip", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList()
    .ForEach(zipFilePath =>
    {
        using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    //entry does not contain MIME type, only filename with extension
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Another solution would be to set the folder's permissions to deny execution, but I don't want to do that because it's something easy to forget.

Lastly, there is some way of storing files in an [App_Data](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160129/c-malicious-file-upload-to-server) folder which isn't publicly available and so files in it can't be directly executed. The issue with that is I just can't find such a folder. It doesn't seem to be created automatically with my app. I'm thinking this must be a difference between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Maybe this can help [Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature).

Comment: Thanks for the link. After looking into it, unfortunately `FindMimeFromData` function does not define most of the MIME types I need.